# compiling with codelite. 'make' is not recognized

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl, codelite

So, I am using Twinklebear's tutorial on setting up SDL2 for MinGW(Website here ---> http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-mingw/). Now, I am using CodeLite 5.4 as my IDE and I don't really know how to tweak my IDE so that it generates the right makefile to run this sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
    }
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the makefile I want to use:

```
CXX = g++
SDL_LIB = -LC:/SDL2Dev/lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2
SDL_INCLUDE = -IC:/SDL2Dev/include
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c++11 $(SDL_INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS = -lmingw32 -mwindows -mconsole $(SDL_LIB)
EXE = SDL_Lesson0.exe

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): main.o
    $(CXX) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    del *.o && del $(EXE)
```

But, when I go to build it, I get this

```
MESSAGE: Entering directory `C:\Users\user\Documents\SDL2Custom\'
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "make"
----------Building project:[ SDL2Custom - Debug ]----------
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

I am extremely new to this stuff as I just depended on my IDE to do the dirty work for me. I really want to use the SDL2 library for making games in the future, so can anyone please explain to me how to do this?

Oh, I do have all the development library downloaded. For me, it's located in C:/SDL2Dev and it contains the 32 bit library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeLite 5.4 installer comes with MinGW bundled (TDM-GCC 4.8.1)
So you probably have it installed (MinGW that is)

However, MinGW uses `mingw32-make.exe` and not `make`
So change that in your project settings:

Right click on the project icon in the tree view (on the left side) or hit Alt+F7
`Settings->Common Settings->Customize->Custom Build`, double click on the `Build` target and change the command to: `mingw32-make.exe -j4`

the `-j4` means: run 4 processes to compile at the same time ( this usually boosts compilation time)

Eran

Comment: I did exactly a you said and now it says => mingw32-make.exe: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: Make sure that a `Makefile` is located in the working directory (assuming you are using custom makefile as the OP)

Answer (score 1):

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The message means the IDE called *make* to build the project, but the operating system could not find any sign of a *make.exe* on that system.

So while the *make.exe* may or may not be installed, what is clear is the executable install folder is not in the system *PATH* environment variable.

**EDIT:** I am assuming you have installed MinGW, in which case look for the make.exe in that install folder and make sure that folder is in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my "make" problem. When creating my project in Codelite 13 I accidently selected c++ instead of G++. It created a file with the .c extension instead of .cpp. I changed the extension and it built and ran fine.